# Loop through column, copy and paste from above if value is 1

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I need a simple macro for a loop through column C. If the value is 1, copy and paste the value from above. End when there are no more Rows based on Column A. Below is example information. In theory Column C, rows with 12345, PCS = 1, should be updated to 6400, and Rows with 67890, PCS=1, should be 2800.

[image]

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count

Next i

If Cells(i, 3).Value = "1" Then ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Comment: Sounds like you have the pseudocode. How have you tried to implement it?

Comment: I have not tried any code yet. I am somewhat new to this. I understand the logic of what I need done but do not have the coding knowledge to create the macro. 
I just need it to go cell by cell in column C and if the value equals 1 copy and paste the value from above. The macro should see the 1 in C2 copy value from C1. C3 should then copy C2, C4 should then copy C3, etc.. Skip the cells that are not 1 (C7). and proceed logic on next cell, C8 should copy C7, etc.

Comment: Well, what have you researched on loops?

Comment: I have not created any loops before. My first instinct was to create a macro that basically took the first value in C, per unique value in B and assign it to all cells in C that match that value in B. The macro gets pretty long though and I ran into a situation where B has a duplicate number but a different value in C. 
I am kind of starting from scratch here as far as the knowledge. But my understanding of loops is for it to go cell by cell and if cell=(x), do this, then go to next cell and do the same thing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your loop attempt.

Comment: I added my simple try. I am sure it is missing something simple like a period somewhere, but my loop vba knowledge is very limited. If you can help adjust this code and help understand how to work this function it would be appreciated.

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row`, `For i = 2 to lastRow`, `If Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value`

Comment: Yes. This works! It was missing a Next for the For, but I added "Next i" at the end and it works. Thank you for the help!